# AngularJS | Is there any way to remove data-ng-include from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I want to remove all `data-ng-include` tags from my AngulaJS App. I found some answers but none satisfies what I want to do.

**I am moving away from AngularJS, and I want to somewhat componentize the views, in order to move to React. For that, I would like to remove `data-ng-include` but retain their properties.**

Example:

```
<div data-ng-include="'menuBar.html'"></div>
```

How do I include the `menuBar` HTML file in another in AngularJS, without ng-include?

I know, there are questions similar to this, but no definitive answer. If you know of a way, it would be awesome, thank you.

Comment: How about Directive? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: No, as i said I want to get away from Angular. It is not the easiest think, but I just cleaned a whole bunch of them, and ported the functionality to Redux so no. Thanks though..

Comment: So, I was just prompted by a friend to an Article, that suggest using components instead. My main gripe with it, is that AngularJS components, are dumb components. Would it be able to do it with using something like `<menu menuBar="menuBar"><menu>` ???

Comment: That is Directive.

Comment: Hhhmm. I must be understanding something wrong about AngularJS then. I thought component and directive are 2 different terms. I will look into it..

Comment: Apart from those AngularJS things, see https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file.

Comment: Component is simply an AngularJS directive with some default settings